# Problems moving POSTGIS database from postgresql 8.3 to 9.3 using Navicat

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I am using Navicat 11 to move a POSTGIS database from 8.3 to 9.3 on Mac OS X 10.9. I have installed PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostGIS with homebrew (brew install postgresql postgis) and everything looks ok. I then create the db locally with template "postgis_template".

Then with Navicat I connect to the remote 8.3 PGSQL, choose the remote db and choose "Data Transfer", choose the remote db, schema public and the local db, schema public. When the transfer starts I get this error:

```
[Msg] [Dtf] Drop table: "geometry_columns"
[Err] [Dtf] Transfer Data [DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "geometry_columns";]:
ERROR:  "geometry_columns" is not a table
HINT:  Use DROP VIEW to remove a view.
[Err] [Dtf] Terminated
```

In PGSQL 8.3 there is a table "geometry_columns" while in 9.3 there is a VIEW with the same name. If I try to delete the VIEW in my new db I get an error that it is need by POSTGIS.

Also after several tries I was able to delete the view but now I get this error and wonder if everything is transfered and if I have to do something:

```
[Msg] [Dtf] End transaction on target server
[Err] [Dtf] Transfer Data [ALTER TABLE "kulturminner" ADD CONSTRAINT "enforce_dims_punkt_geom" CHECK ((ndims(punkt_geom) = 2)) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;]:
ERROR:  function ndims(geometry) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[Err] [Dtf] Terminated
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I strongly recommend following the PostGIS upgrade documentation and using `pg_dump`.

Comment: I tried to use pg_dump but I get the same problem. On my old postgres 8.3 table there is a table "geometry_columns" while postgres 9.3 and POSTGIS 2.1 creates a view with the same name "geometry_columns". I am not able to delete this and I wonder if it is safe to delete it? I tried to do it on a test database and after that the import complained about missing geom functions. This is driving me nuts :-(

Comment: http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#upgrading

Comment: I am not sure I did this correctly since I am confused with the how POSTGIS 2.1 has a view "geometry_columns" while the old POSTGIS 2.0 creates a table with the same name. I was able to drop til view and create the table. Then I imported the backup sql file. At least everything shows up now in Geoserver correctly and my maps seem to work fine.